# Verificar se o valor da coluna é "Base"

Tags: php, codeigniter

Necessitava de verificar se na tabela `mytable`, na coluna `mycolumn`, o valor é `'meuvalor'`.

O meu controller:

```
public function GetValue()
    {
            $this->config->set_item('language', $this->session->errorMessagesLang);
            $this->load->library('parser');
            $name= $this->admin_model->getmycolumn();
            if($name['mycolumn'] == 'meuvalor'){
                //fazer o que eu quero
            }
            echo $result;}
```

O meu model:

```
public function getmycolumn()
    {
        $this->db->select('mycolumn');
        $this->db->from('mytable');
        $result = $this->db->get()->result();
        return $result;
    }
```

O meu problema é o ifstatement, este não está a conseguir resolver o meu código, ou seja nao verifica, penso ter a ver com isto:

```
$name['mycolumn'] == 'meuvalor'
```

não me parece ser a sintaxe certa.

Todo o tipo de ajuda é bem-vinda!
PS: Só quero deixar claro que consigo ir buscar o valor à tabela, só quero verificar se tem dentro dele o valor que eu quero.

Answer (score 0):

Faz assim:

```
$name['mytable'][0]->mycolumn == 'meuvalor'
```

Comment: Já resolvi, vou pôr aqui a resposta para pessoas futuras que tiverem este problema, ou parecido. Mas muito obrigado à mesma!

Answer (score 0):

No meu model, vou buscar todos os dados e colunas da minha tabela, retorno isso, após isso, o controlador guarda os dados na variavel $name, e para fazer referência à minha coluna basta referenciar isso após a variavel pondo (conforme necessário) $name['mycolumn']. Ou seja a minha sintaxe estava correta, porém o erro era no model, que me enviava os valores em string, desta forma são enviados no tipo array e não dá qualquer erro, pelo menos da forma que eu estou a utilizar!

O meu controlador:

```
public function GetValue()
    {
            $this->config->set_item('language', $this->session->errorMessagesLang);
            $this->load->library('parser');
            $name = $this->admin_model->getmycolumn();
            if($name['mycolumn'] == 'meuvalor'){
                    //$result = Fazer oq que eu quero
                    //echo $result;
            }
            elseif($name['mycolumn'] == 'meuvalor2'){
                //$result = Fazer oq que eu quero
                //echo $result;
            }     
    }
```

O meu model:

```
 public function getmycolumn() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM mytable;");
    $row = $query->row_array();
    return $row;
}
```